# SQLServer with DBeaver. Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:

Tags: sql-server, authentication, dbeaver

I'm trying to connect to SQLServer with DBeaver on MacOS using these settings:

[image]

And I keep having the same error:

> "Login failed for user 'sa'.
>   ClientConnectionId:bab6f002-ac7c-4125-b8e8-169c498e79bc"

I read online about changing the Security in the Proprieties and putting SQL Server and Windows mixed authentication, but I could not found the Security settings on DBeaver. The menu in the image just have either Windows or SQL Server authentication but not a mixed one.

The string after "ClientConnectionId" keeps changing.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't run on MacOS, so it would be impossible for you to connect to it. You need to pass the hostname/IP Address of the host that the SQL Server Instance is running on.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Docker to run it, so I tried the IP 172.17.0.2 to reach the first container on docker. Now the error is changed, it says the SQL Server is not running, but I started it with 'sudo docker start sql1' (sql1 is the docker container of SQL Server).

Comment: Is your SQL Server configured to use mixed-mode authentication?

Comment: Very unlikely if it's running on Docker @Fleshy, it'll be SQL Authentication only. Getting AD on the Linux versions takes a bit of work,

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by setting the **Server Safety**  into **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode**.

[Image of the option in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OWjz.png)

I think maybe when I install it choose **use only Windows Authentication mode** cause.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1) Go to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:
Choose your connection, right click -> Properties -> Security -> Server authentication -> Pick radio button "Sql Server and Windows Authentication mode"

2) After that go to SQL Server Configuration Manager:
SQL Server Services -> restart SQLEXPRESS and MSSQLSERVER

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but on debian 11. I fixed it by installing the ODBC driver

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#debian18

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting the host to 0.0.0.0

I found the IP writing

```
docker ps -a
```

in the terminal and looking at the PORTS field of the SQL container I created.

Thanks for the hint on what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but I solved it by changing my password. I had @ in my password and it somehow was not able to use it.

Just leaving it here for others. I know it's pretty basic but it might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the combined Windows and SQL authentication option but I used [this](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1279#issuecomment-708049668) Github answer instead. The trick was to change the authentication to NTLM.